# Glyphicon's boostrap 3 not working in chrome extensions?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm start learning create an extension in chrome. I had a problem that Chrome does not accept any glyphicon icon using in boostrap version 3, like this:

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"></span>
```

I tried config bootstrap in *content.js* file or call it in html's file but it still didn't work. Here are some in my mini project:

- Chrome does not recognize icon.

  [image: In browser].
- In my source code *manifest.json*, I have configured chrome to receive bootstrap:

  ```
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    "/assets/*",
    "/css/*",
    "/js/DomAnalys/*"
  ],
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "https://*/*",
        "http://*/*"
      ],
      "all_frames": true,
      "js": [
        "/assets/js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js",
        "/assets/js/bootstrap-3.4.1.min.js",
        "/js/content.js"
      ],
      "css": []
    }
  ]
  ```
- I also configured embedded boostrap directly into the js file. But
  nothing happened. Here is my content.js file, i attached boostrap to
  shadow dom:

  ```
  const urlCssContent = chrome.extension.getURL("/css/content-script.css");
  const urlCssBoostrap = chrome.extension.getURL("/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css");
  const shadow = document.querySelector('#popup-modal-transl').attachShadow({
      mode: 'open'
  });
  const importCss = `<style>
                              @import "${urlCssContent}";
                              @import "${urlCssBoostrap}";
                          </style>`;
  shadow.innerHTML = `${importCss}${content}`;
  ```

Comment: i edited my post, thanks @wOxxOm

Comment: 1) The  `const importCss` line is invalid because there's `;` instead of `+` (tip: use a JavaScript IDE like VSCode or Atom with a ESLint plugin). 2) The problem may be also inside CSS files if they reference resources using relative paths (in that case you need to use `chrome-extension://__MSG_@@extension_id__/assets/foo.png`, see [the documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/i18n#overview-predefined)).

Comment: Did you inspect the dev console to see if there were any errors? Do you have the font files in place? Did the fonts load? Check the inspector and network tabs and provide more information.

Comment: @hello mtyj, 1, I checked my dev console many time but no error happened. 2, I am downloaded library in homepage of bootstrap then using it in local. 3, i just have checked font and it not loaded,  what happened with it? can you give me some tips?. thanks

Comment: @wOxxOm 1, Sorry about that, i am have some trouble with '`' so i rewrite my code and not check it again. I edited my post. Thanks so much. 2, im using boostrap 3 then i configured it in manifest.json file, i do not use any relative paths in my custom css file. :(((

Comment: Sounds like the imports don't work. Instead of using them, simply make two `<style>` elements and set their `src` to urlCssContent and urlCssBoostrap  respectively.

Comment: No, i use other bootstrap components they still work like bootstrap alert or tooltips. Including my optional css. Glyphicon only are not working. :( @wOxxOm

Comment: I don't know bootstrap but it sounds like some resources are missing or not loaded as usually this is done by loading a font. But you said there are no resources linked in CSS? Another possibility is that bootstrap JS is processing the elements so I guess it can't process stuff inside ShadowDOM automatically.